# Вызов функций из других лямбда-функций

Tags: java

Синтаксически все верно, но присутствует баг(фича)... может кто объяснить?

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Hello {
Runnable r1 = () -> out.println(this);
Runnable r2 = () -> out.println(toString());

public String toString() { return "Hello, world!"; }

public static void main(String... args) {
    new Hello().r1.run(); //Hello, world!
    new Hello().r2.run(); //Hello, world!
    }
}
```

Cуть/идея: метод run() вызывается в текущем потоке, метод start() запускается в новом потоке и вызывает метод run() который выполняется параллельно.

Comment: А в чем баг то заключается?

Comment: без понятия, мб "не баг, а фича" ... вопрос с подвохом от препода

Answer (score 5):

Вы не создаёте потоки. Вызов метода `run()` класса, реализующего интерфейс `Runnable` не является созданием нового потока, код выполняется в том потоке, где он был вызван. Для того, чтобы запустить код в отдельном потоке, следует завернуть его в [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

```
Thread tread = new Thread(new Hello().r1);
thread.start();
```

Отдельное внимание обращаю на то, что нельзя использовать `thread.run()`, в этом случае код выполнится в этом же потоке.

Также непонятно, как вы хотите продемонстрировать многопоточное выполнение таким кодом. Методы выполняются настолько быстро, что вряд ли планировщик ОС или JVM будет прерывать выполнение одного из них для того, чтобы выполнить другой. Для демонстрации многопоточности стоит запустить бесконечные или очень долгие циклы в обоих потоках.